# Type constructor bounded by proper type

Tags: scala, generics, type-constraints, higher-kinded-types, type-constructor

Consider the following type parameter clause `[F[_] <: Int]` in

```
def h[F[_] <: Int] = ???
```

where a type constructor `F` is bounded by the proper type `Int`. Now both `h[List]` and `h[Int]` are illegal

```
scala> def h[F[_] <: Int] = ???
     |
def h[F[_] <: Int]: Nothing

scala> h[List]
        ^
       error: type arguments [List] do not conform to method h's type parameter bounds [F[_] <: Int]

scala> h[Int]
         ^
       error: Int takes no type parameters, expected: 1
```

so why is then `[F[_] <: Int]` legal?

Comment: You can do this: `type Test[A] = 3` _(or any other **Int**, or **Int** itself)_ and then you can call `h[Test]`.

Comment: You can consider `F[_ <: A] <: B` as type-level analog of `f: A => B`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type parameter declaration `F[_] <: Int` means that *every instantiation of `F`* must be a subtype of `Int`. It's right in the syntax, though cryptic: `F` does not have to be a subtype of `Int`; `F[_]` has to be a subtype of `Int` (for all types that may be placed in the `_`). An example of such an `F` is one which always returns `Int`:

```
type ConstInt[X] = Int
h[ConstInt] // compiles
```

Note that you can name the type in the `_`. E.g. I can declare a type parameter `F[X] <: X`. `X` is local to the declaration, defined by appearing under `F` on the left, used as a bound on the right, and going out of scope afterwards. This example means that `F[X]` must be a subtype of `X`, e.g. as in

```
def f[F[X] <: X] = ???
type Identity[X] = X
f[Identity] // works
type ConstNothing[X] = Nothing
f[ConstNothing] // works
// f[ConstInt] (ConstInt[X] = Int is not always a subtype of X; counterexample X = AnyRef)
```

Perhaps that drives home what the bound is supposed to mean.