# Difference in inference between [F <: List[A], A] and [F[_] <: List[A], A]

Tags: scala, type-inference, scala-3, type-constructor

Consider the difference in inference of type argument `A` to type constructors in the following two type parameter clauses

```
$ scala3-repl
scala> def f[F <: List[A], A](as: F) = as
def f[F <: List[A], A](as: F): F

scala> f(List(42))
val res0: List[Int] = List(42)

scala> def f[F[_] <: List[A], A](as: F[A]) = as
def f[F[_$1] <: List[A], A](as: F[A]): F[A]

scala> f(List(42))
val res1: List[Any] = List(42)
```

Why is type argument `A` to type constructor `F` inferred as `Any` in second case?

Comment: It's how Scala compiler works with wildcard type argument with no type bound. It will just infer as `Any`. If there is type bound, it will be something like `$1 where xxxx <: xxxxx`. In your case, you probably wanna specify the type constructor takes an argument that is the same as you passed to List: `def f[F[X] <: List[X], A](as: F[A])`. Then you will get a List[Int] in your case

Comment: @texasbruce Isn’t there no type argument bound in the first case as well?

Comment: In the first case, F is not a type constructor, but a full type which is a subtype of List[A]. And when you pass a List[Int], F is registered in the compiler as List[Int]. In the second case of type constructor, the compiler just noted that F is a type constructor that takes Any (because you pass a wildcard), and List[A] (which is inferred as List[Int]) is more specific, and you are trying to return F[A] (automatically inferred) as List[Int] so A must be Any. (It will fail in Scala2) In @yangzai's answer, both F and List are taking Any so it will work as well.

Comment: @MarioGalic in the 2nd case if you explicitly make `A` an `Int` like `f[List, Int](List(42))` it won't compile. All in all, in both cases the inferred type is already the narrowest possible type.

Comment: @texasbruce In the first case compiler was able to deconstruct proper type `List[Int]` to pick out `Int` for `A`, which was not the case in Scala 2, so it seems more is going on than simply assigning `List[Int]` to `F`.

Comment: @yangzai Regarding the edit on the question to add the `[higher-kinded-type]` tag, I do not think there are any higher kinded types at play. `trait G[F[_]]` is higher kinded, but `trait F[_]` is first order as per `:kind -v` command in REPL.

Comment: @MarioGalic sure

Comment: It's true Scala 2 cannot deconstruct F and infer A as Int. It would simply infer `A` as `Nothing`, and `F` as `List[Int]`, but it conflicts with `F <: List[A]` because `List[Int]` does not `<: List[Nothing]` so it gives error, which is expected. See here: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/mCPTZSI4SXOYSilCJkA4kA

Comment: Anyhow like case 1, case 2 needs to be explicit in Scala 2 as well `f[List, Any](List(42))`

Comment: Assuming `F[_ <: A] <: B` as [type-level analog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62439636/type-constructor-bounded-by-proper-type#comment110439190_62439636) of `f: A => B`,  let `[F[_ <: Int] <: List[Int], A <: Int]`, then should't type application `F[A]` yield `List[Int]`, so in this case `f(List(42))` should compile?

Comment: @MarioGalic I don't think so. Since `F` is `List`, `F[x]` should be a subtype of `F[A]` for all `x`. So if `A` were inferred as `Int`, `F[String]` would not be a subtype of `List[Int]`. (basically what yangzai said)

Comment: @user Ah I do not understand :( Why for all x, when `x <: Int` in `F[x <: Int]`?

Comment: Because you have no bounds on the parameter to `F`. So `F` must conform to `List[A]` when its parameter is anything between `Any` and `Nothing`. (unless you are talking about a different bound `[F[_ <: A] <: List[A], A]`?)

Comment: @user Indeed, I would think the first case is effectively the same as  `[F[_ <: A] <: List[A], A]`.

Comment: @MarioGalic I don't understand which first case you're talking about now. Are you talking about `def f[F <: List[A], A](as: F) = as`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231040/discussion-between-user-and-mario-galic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a full-fledged answer, just some food for thought: I've attempted to construct a counter-example, but couldn't quite come up with anything that would actually result in unsoundness under the assumption that `A` would be inferred as the narrowest type. Still, maybe you find it interesting.

Here is a function `h` with similar constraints, but instead of `List`, we take slightly different type constructors.

The main idea is that `Cc` has two separate type parameters:

- The first is what is meant by `_` in `F[_]`
- The second one is the one that interacts with `A` in the `<: Lst[A]`-constraint

Note that this would not compile if the `A` was inferred to be the narrowest type (`Nothing`):

```
(run in 3.0.0-RC2)

scala> trait Lst[+X]
// defined trait Lst

scala> case class Cc[+I, +X](i: I) extends Lst[X]
// defined case class Cc

scala> type T[+I] = Cc[I, Nothing]
// defined alias type T[+I] = Cc[I, Nothing]

scala> def h[F[_] <: Lst[A], A](as: F[A]) = as
def h[F[_$1] <: Lst[A], A](as: F[A]): F[A]

scala> val xs: T[Int] = Cc(42)
val xs: T[Int] = Cc(42)

scala> h(xs)                                                                                             
val res9: Cc[Int, Nothing] = Cc(42)
```

Had `A` been inferred as the narrowest possible type satisfying the constraint of `<: Lst[A]`, then `A` would be `Nothing`, and the argument would have to be of type `T[Nothing] = Cc[Nothing, Nothing]`, which is uninhabited.

I think it's interesting, but I don't see why it would actually be bad if it didn't compile.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my interpretation of your definition in the 2nd case, `F[_]` is a `List` type constructor, but `List[A]` has to be an upper bound on any list `F[_]` can construct, so `A` has to be `Any`.

Probably what you were going for is this:

```scala
def f[F[_] <: List[_], A](as: F[A]) = as
```

Or

```scala
def f[F[x] <: List[x], A](as: F[A]) = as
```

especially for cases where `x` needs to be fixed to multiple constraint parameters (for an example please refer to @user comments below)

In the 1st case `F` is a concrete type so `List[A]` isn't an upper-bound on all list, but only on list `F`, so `A` doesn't have to be `Any` and the narrowest inferable type would be `Int`.

Comment: Why is then Int inferred in the first case when constraint seems the same? What is the difference?

Comment: @MarioGalic I've updated the answer to cover the 1st case. Don't know if it's clear enough. In both cases the narrowest possible type is already inferred.

Comment: Should it be `F[_] <: List[_]` or something like `F[x] <: List[x]`?

Comment: @user I think both should work. I don't know if there's a difference. If you find an example that only works on 1 case you can let me know.

Comment: I think both work in this case, but if you want to perform operations on `as`, you'll need to use something other than an underscore and a wildcard. That said, `F[x] <: List[x]` does produce errors too, so you'd need `IterableOps`. [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/HpeS6OQMRaaxVzjTpB1QdA)

Comment: @user I will add that as an alternative then